# Django hit counts Class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to do something like youtube views:

```
models.py
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    embed = models.TextField
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_add=True,editable=False)
    visit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def add_visit(self):
        if self.visit_count is not None:
            self.visit_count += 1
        else:
            self.visit_count = 0

views.py
class VideoDetail(DetailView):
    model = Video

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(VideoDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object.add_visit()
        self.object.save()
        return context

Example use:
    Video.objects.order_by('-visit_count')
```

So is everything working properly, but not quite, as I can count limit by IP.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    embed = models.TextField
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_add=True,editable=False)

class Visit(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    ip = models.IPAddressField()
    visit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How to insert in views or models: visit_count,ip,video.

Answer (score 1):

In the view:

```
def get(self, req, *k, **kw)
   is_created, visit = Visit.objects.get_or_create(this.object, ip)
   if is_created:
      this.object.add(visit)
   else: 
      visit.count +=1
      visit.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd extend your `add_visit()` model method with IP address:

```
def add_visit(self, ip):
    _, visit = Visit.objects.get_or_create(self, ip)
    visit.count += 1
```

And use your DetailView as is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **get_object** is the method that retrieves the object

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Author

class AuthorDetailView(DetailView):

    queryset = Author.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        # Record the last accessed date
        obj.last_accessed = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/